# What does 当然 mean in this context?

Tags: translation, meaning

I'm trying to translate this video -> [link](https://youtu.be/zIwF3jH7534?t=2m) and I got stuck at the last bit, where the speaker mention "**当然**"

so this is the transcription,

> まあ、演劇「ハイキュー」自体はやっぱり春も新作があるので、続くんですね。
>
> 漫画原作だから、こう、**当然**だろうと思う人もいると思うんですが、
>
> 僕はこの**当然**なことが一番素敵で本当に偉大なことだと思います。
>
> こういう、素敵な**当然**の中に居させてくれて、ありがとうございました。

I search the meaning on [Jishou](http://jisho.org/search/%E5%BD%93%E7%84%B6) and
I still couldn't really grasp the meaning of it in his speech.

Translation attempt; **This is wrong BTW**

> 漫画原作だから、こう、**当然**だろうと思う人もいると思うんですが、

= Because of the original manga, I think there are people, who are **certain(?)** about that.

> 僕はこの**当然**なことが一番素敵で本当に偉大なことだと思います。

= For me, this "**certainty**" is the most wonderful and it's truly the greatest thing.

> こういう、素敵な**当然**の中に居させてくれて、ありがとうございました。

Thank you for letting me be in this wonderful **place(?)** <- like I said I'm so confused with this...

Comment: How about providing us with your "best guess" translation first, so we can see how close (or far) off the mark you are and help you figure it out?

Comment: @Philippe I just updated my poor translation attempt... OTL

Comment: Hmm... I'm curious why you used "certain" while the dictionary never suggests such a word. (It's certain that my English is not enough good, though.)

Comment: @broccoliforest I think it usually means "of course" or "naturally" right? For example, A naturally causes B, so I thought 当然だろうと思う人 = People, who naturally think that = People who are certain that (to make it more colloquial). **BTW this may not be correct, but I just wanna share my thought process**

Comment: From what I understand, and what seems to be the reason for your uncertainty, the first sentence says that "there are people, who will say that 'of course this gets a theatrical play, it's based on a manga series after all, right?'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This 当然 just means "natural consequence", "necessity", "inevitability", "unsurprising fact", etc.

> 漫画(が)原作だから、こう、当然だろうと思う人もいると思うんですが、
>   Because it (=stage play of Haikyu!!) has an original manga, well, I think some will think that (=the fact that the stage play will continue) is natural/unsurprising, but...
>
> 僕はこの当然なことが一番素敵で本当に偉大なことだと思います。
>   I think this "being unsurprising" is a really wonderful and great thing.

The last sentence is tricky and somewhat poetic, but こういう素敵な当然 (literally "this wonderful unsurprising-ness") refers to what was said in the previous sentence. So basically what he wants to say is "thank you for letting me participate in this play, and for the wonderful fact that the play continues to the next sequel without trouble."

**EDIT:** 当然 is usually not a positive-sounding word, so you may call this 素敵な当然 an example of oxymoron.

Comment: I see, I think it was the last sentence that confused me and led me to think that it could have other meanings. Thank you ^ ^